# C++/CLI Copy ValuePairs to a seperate Dictionary

Tags: c++, dictionary, clone

First off, I want to refer to my last question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31823483/c-cli-set-a-property-to-primarykey

So I got this fixed by the answer I did not find in the first place.

Now the Code looks like this:

```
public: void SetData(Generic::Dictionary<String^,TypeName>^ Dic) {

    array<KeyValuePair<String^,TypeName>^>^ TempConv = gcnew array<KeyValuePair<String^, TypeName>^>(Dic->Count);
    ((Generic::Dictionary<String^, TypeName>^)Dic)->CopyTo(TempConv,0);
    TempEntityDic = gcnew Dictionary<String^, TypeName>(Dic);
    DataListe = gcnew List<TypeName>();

    for each(KeyValuePair<String^,TypeName>^ t in TempConv){        
        DataListe->Add(t->Value);
    }

    // Creating Bindable List
    BindingDataListe = gcnew BindingList<TypeName>(DataListe);

    BindingDataListe->AddingNew += gcnew System::ComponentModel::AddingNewEventHandler(this, &mepla_iso::Visualisation::ListenAnsicht<TypeName>::OnAddingNew);

    // Source festlegen
    ListenAnsichtGrid->DataSource = BindingDataListe;

    // Display the column Name first
    ListenAnsichtGrid->Columns["Name"]->DefaultCellStyle->Font = gcnew Drawing::Font(gcnew Drawing::Font("Consolas", 12), Drawing::FontStyle::Bold);
    ListenAnsichtGrid->Columns["Name"]->DisplayIndex = 0;

}
```

The Problem I am currently encountering is that my TempEntityDic (temporary Dictionary) is not a temporary Dictionary. The Code above won't even compile correctly. Error Message:

`System::Collections::Generic::ICollection<System::Collections::Generic::KeyValuePair<System::String ^,TypeName>>::CopyTo': 
    the function template cannot convert parameter 1 from type 'cli::array<System::Collections::Generic::KeyValuePair<System::String ^,TypeName> ^,1> ^`

Previously I tried:

```
public: void SetData(...){
    TempEntityDic = gcnew Dictionary<String^, TypeName>(Dic);
    DataListe = gcnew List<TypeName>();

    for each(TypeName t in TempEntityDic){      
        DataListe->Add(t);

  [...............]
}
```

But it was the same there. Whenever I change something in my `DataGridView`, I also got the change done to `Dic` (parameter in `SetData()`).

**Question 1** What is the best way to make a copy and not a reference of my parameter "Dic"?
**Question 2** How do I get the `CopyTo()` working, so that I can afterwards add all the `KeyValuePairs` in `TempConv` into my `DataListe`?

Thanks for your help. :)

**EDIT**
To make things clear: In the End I want to have two separate dictionaries. If needed, I want to override the first with the second.

### **EDIT 2**

Hello again, here is my code again. I am still trying to get things working, but I just don't get a solution.

```
public: void SetData(Generic::Dictionary<String^,TypeName>^ Dic) {
    //HACK: Kopie von Dic erstellen - Keine Reference
    array<KeyValuePair<String^,TypeName>>^ TempConv = gcnew array<KeyValuePair<String^, TypeName>>(Dic->Values->Count);
    ((Generic::IDictionary<String^, TypeName>^)Dic)->CopyTo(TempConv,0);


    Dictionary<String^, TypeName>^ TempEntityDic = gcnew Dictionary<String^, TypeName>();

    for each(KeyValuePair<String^, TypeName> t in Dic)
        TempEntityDic->Add(t.Key,t.Value);

    Dic = gcnew Dictionary<String^, TypeName>(TempEntityDic);

    DataListe = gcnew List<TypeName>(Dic->Values);

    // Creating Bindable List
    BindingDataListe = gcnew BindingList<TypeName>(DataListe);


    // Source festlegen
    ListenAnsichtGrid->DataSource = BindingDataListe;
    // Display the column Name 
    ListenAnsichtGrid->Columns["Name"]->DefaultCellStyle->Font = gcnew Drawing::Font(gcnew Drawing::Font("Consolas", 12), Drawing::FontStyle::Bold);
    ListenAnsichtGrid->Columns["Name"]->DisplayIndex = 0;

}
```

I am also trying here, to create a new Instance of Dic in TempEntityDic and then copy it again the other way around, but that doesn't work at all.

Could you please help me? I just cant get it to create a separate Dictionary without reference to the first one.

Comment: I'm not up on my CLI, but odds are pretty good that because practically everything is a pointer, you're copying the pointers and your copy winds up pointing at the same places as the originals.

Comment: It is just a one-liner: `auto DataListe = gcnew List<TypeName>(Dic->Values);`

Comment: @Hans Passant I tried your suggestion but I am still copying the references. I used exactly what you wrote (and the code makes sense) but no difference.

Comment: Erm, no way you can get the exact same compile error message.

Comment: @Hans Passant No its not the error message. The implementation works fine but I still got references and not copies. When I change something in DataList I am still changing the same object in `Dic->Values`

Comment: Ask only one question.

Comment: @Hans Passant Sorry for the inconvenience. Still, do you have a solution to the reference-problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85323/discussion-between-leon-b-and-hans-passant).

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary.CopyTo copies values only, not key-value pairs - it seems to be your error. Use `array<TypeName>^` instead of `array<KeyValuePair<String^, TypeName>^>^`.

Comment: I tried to do what you supposed like this:

    array<TypeName>^ TempConv = gcnew array<TypeName>(Dic->Values->Count);

    ((Generic::IDictionary<String^, TypeName>^)Dic)->CopyTo(TempConv,0);`

But it throws the same error as above:
    System::Collections::Generic::ICollection<System::Collections::Generic::KeyValuePair<System::String ^,TypeName>>::CopyTo': the function template cannot convert parameter 1 from type 'cli::array<TypeName,1> ^'`

What am I missing?

Comment: Alright, got my Code fixed. As the KeyValuePair-Class is not a managed class I do not need the reference to an object after defining the class. My fault was here:

    array<KeyValuePair<String^,TypeName>^>^ TempConv = gcnew array<KeyValuePair<String^, TypeName>>(Dic->Values->Count);
                                        

After removing the Reference-Symbol `^` , I can compile the file.

-> `array<KeyValuePair<String^,TypeName>>^ TempConv = ....`

Comment: Still, changing everything including the Objects in the Dictionary I do not want to change.